# JQuery Neosmart Plugin - How Long Will FaceBook access_token last?

Tags: jquery, facebook, access-token

I'm using the JQquery Neosmart fb.wall plugin:

- http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall

It now requires a FaceBook access_token. I can get the access_token.

My question is:

**How long will the access_token last?**

Do I need to get a new access_token each time someone views my webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request offline_access access, that token is valid until they revoke access to your app or change their password.  Otherwise, the tokens are generally valid for an hour (the time till it expires in seconds is at the end of the token, the 'expires' parameter).

Answer (score 0):

offline_access was deprecated by Facebook - therefore we developed neosmart STREAM - the offical successor of fb.wall - neosmart STREAM includes an access token creator, which creates long-life access token (60 days) with a few clicks: Download and Live demo on https://neosmart-stream.de